# Tablet antitampering

Tags: mobile, corporate-policy

We'll be distributing tablets for some group of employees. Enterprise applications will be installed and IT has been tasked with protecting them against users messing with these new toys (i.e uninstalling enterprise applications, installing games or extremely bandwidth consuming apps,etc.)
What kind of technical solution we should be looking for?

Comment: Is this iOS, Android, Windows, a mix?

Answer (score 2):

Mobile Device Management (MDM) Software is enterprise software that covers the management of applications and device security. MDM software varies in capabilities depending on the operating system (Android, iOS, Windows) you are supporting.

Some commercial MDM solutions will include the ability to manage multiple operating systems while others are tailored to specific operating systems.

Some commercial MDM solutions include:

- [AirWatch](http://www.air-watch.com/solutions/android/)
- [Good](https://www1.good.com/secure-mobility-solution/mobile-device-management.html)
- [MobileIron](https://www.mobileiron.com/en/solutions/mobile-device-management-mdm)

Operating Systems offer different levels of control, but most MDM software will allow you to:

- Preinstall and restrict uninstallation of enterprise applications
- Enforce password policies
- Deploy client SSL/TLS Certificates
- Deploy WPA2-EPA Certificates
- Physically locate or remote wipe devices

Comment: Does any mobile OS come with any embedded control with this security feature? An embedded control that provides similar features like MDM (at least restriction on uninstalling apps). Something similar to user profiles in Windows.

Comment: What do you mean by embedded control?

Comment: An embedded control that provides similar features like MDM (at least restriction on uninstalling apps). Something similar to user profiles in Windows